# Catalog Management is empty after HabitatHome Commerce Setup

Tags: sitecore-commerce, habitat, commerce-catalog

I do no see the **Catalog Management**(*sitecore > Commerce > Catalog Management*) showing up any data. This is after done with the setup of Habitat Home commerce on Sitecore commerce 9 update 2.
All the templates related to commerce and Catalogs are present and *Update Data Templates* work without any errors.
I do not see any errors in the logs.

What I need to do so that I can fetch it?

[image]

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: The only option I found out is re-installation. No idea yet on how to fix it. steps tried to make it work without re-installation are 'update data templates' and 'refresh commerce cache', re-publish, re-index etc

Answer (score 0):

You can check your Store-frontend settings, under:
**/sitecore/Commerce/Commerce Control Panel/Storefront Settings/Storefronts/Storefront/Catalog Configuration**

[image: Storefrontend configuration]

if you navigate there you will find the catalog:

[image: Catalog]
As you can see **"Habitat Master"** is set as the selected Catalog there.

furthermore you can run the sql query on the Sharedenvironment:

```
    SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,[EnvironmentId]
      ,[Version]
      ,[Entity]
      ,[EntityVersion]
      ,[Published]
  FROM [SitecoreCommerce9_SharedEnvironments].[dbo].[CatalogEntities]
  where id like '%Habitat%Master'
```

if you check the entity you will see the parrent id of the catalog in sitecore:
[image]